# Revoke facebook permission using facebook c# SDK

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to revoke the user permission using the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
        var fbContext = FacebookContext.Current;
        fbContext.Application = new FacebookApplication()
        {
            AppId = ### ,
            AppSecret = ###
        };

        fbContext.Authorize(
            new string[] {"user_likes","email",..},
            {AppUrl},
            {TabUrl}
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

yes:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var res = fb.Delete("me/permissions");

if (res is bool && (bool)res == true)
{
    // Facebook access token has been successfully revoked
}
```

see the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permsdelete